# Decode Shift-JIS and display to user interface using QT

Tags: qt

I have a code to decode SHIFT-JIS using qt to user interface, here is my code:

```
QTextCodec *codec1 = QTextCodec::codecForName("Shift-JIS");
QByteArray encoded = "81ff"; 
QString current = codec->toUnicode(QByteArray::fromHex(encoded));
ui->hientai->setText(current);
```

And the result of my code is wrong. So please tell me what is the problem?

This is the output to UI

[image]

Comment: Hi, I know the problem is the encoded was wrong and I can solve my problem

Comment: The character(0x81ff) is not defined in the Shift-JIS characters set. So its result value is an invalid character.